# What applications do a good job of using the iPad's retina display for stock data?

Tags: ipad, display

I have a few leads, but wanted to know what people feel is an excellent stock price data-visualization and data-exploration app on a retina iPad display.

Excellent would include:

- very clear data with multitouch features for zooming, selecting price points or data ranges.
- more native iOS features than simply a web view app (unless that web view stands on equal ground with a native stock app)
- is equal to or better than the iPhone stock app in terms of features, polish, ease of use and data viewing function.
- some basic import / export capabilities for portfolio management (extra credit - not mandatory)
- simple averages and overlays to see trends and not just the open/close/range volume data (extra credit)
- no ads or the option to pay money to avoid advertisements on the screen

Excellent doesn't necessarily mean:

- Real-time data feed (although a solution that required a lot of steps to refresh the data on a daily basis would be far less useful than an app that could tap into a feed of data that was market delayed.)
- derivative and super complicated analysis lines that are more appropriate for professional trading software (and I would expect to cost hundreds of dollars)
- portfolio management
- actual trading - I'm looking for historical data - not a platform for executing trades. Don't rule out a trading app if it otherwise meets the requirements and is open to anyone with a reasonably low bar to entry (like opening an account with $50 or such)

It doesn't matter if you need to buy the app or if it has an optional or mandatory data service that feeds the data (but please call that out if makes or breaks the app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one app that seems closest to my criteria at the moment is MarketDash by Yahoo.

It does have some retina optimization, but the graphics of stock price itself are somewhat chunky and not as nice as I would like.

It has some multitouch gestures, but the app feels laggy and slow much of the time. Simple swipes work well, but pinch and zoom not so much.

It has ads that I would rather pay to get rid of, but cannot see an option for that presently.

If you don't mind sharing your stock symbols with yahoo - it allows you to load a portfolio from their finance web site, so that is quite nice. You also can set up a portfolio on the device.

Overall the design is quite nice with dark gradients, tasteful color scheme and all the expected things like "links to news articles for the companies you  have selected". Unfortunately, most of those links direct you to spas screens asking you to install other iPad apps, rather than the content. Once you navigate the slash screen promos - the sites it links to are ad heavy and not as useful as mobile news sites like the NYTimes or Wall Street Journal.

This is the best app I have found, but it's only good in comparison to the rest. I wouldn't recommend it highly for making good use of the retina display. It is free and obviously intended to drive traffic to yahoo and it's partner sites and does serve up accurate, timely stock data on the iPad.

Answer (score 1):

I know that [AllMyShares](http://itunes.apple.com/au/app/allmyshares/id367971107?mt=8) is highly regarded (one of the developers attends my CocoaHeads group in Melbourne) and I've confirmed they are planning a retina display update. If you like it, it might be worth adopting this one.

Here's the [website](http://allmyshares.com/) for an overview, lots of videos, screenshots etc.

Answer (score -1):

When it comes to nice looking Data visualisation, I think you should have a look at [Roambi Analytics Visualizer](http://itunes.apple.com/app/roambi-analytics-visualizer/id315020789?mt=8), even if I´m not sure if it fulfils all your wishes.

Comment: Hmm - I assumed too much in my question. I added a requirement to have a data feed if possible. Even if I paid the $99 per year fee for the pro version, Does this app have a way to update the data or does it just allow exploration of data that I have previously saved to an Excel spreadsheet?